# Joomla 3.4.x- Embed an auto image resizer in a custom component

Tags: php, image, joomla, resize

I wrote a component that also has an Admin backend. The administrator has the ability to upload a set of images that they will be available in the front end. Everything works fine in my component but in order for it not to break, I need to keep a set size of the uploaded images.

My backend has a "New" button and when I press it, it shows the upload image form field(I created the form using type="media" in order to get the joomla built-in image uploader). If I press "Save & Close" then the images save correctly.

**My question is if it's possible to process the image after I press the "Save & Close" button and in which file I need to add my resize code.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks but the nature of my question doesnt include code. If someone is familiar with Joomla MVC model he will be able to answer me with a sentence :)

Comment: Yes use JImage. You can look at the J repository discussion of the new media manager ...  depending on your structure you could do this as a postSaveHook (I'm assuming you are using the legacy MVC).